# Using select query with datetime as parameter throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I want to count the number of records between a certain time period.

Using Npgsql I prepare the query, and add the variable parts later (for security reasons):

```
  lCommand.CommandText = 
   "select count(*) from eggs where machineserial = :p1 and timestamp > :p2 and timestamp < :p3;";
  lCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", mId);
  lCommand.Parameters.Add("p2", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp);
  lCommand.Parameters["p2"].Value = aStartDate;
  lCommand.Parameters.Add("p3", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp);
  lCommand.Parameters["p3"].Value = aEndDate ;
  int lNumberEggs = 0;

  try
  {
    lNumberEggs = (int)await lCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync();
  }
  finally
  {
    Helpers.clsDatabaseHelper.FinishCommand(lCommand);
  }
```

When executing the query, it crashes with an InvalidCastException.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured out what I did wrong.

Ofcourse, there is a cast, which is the `(int)` in front of the `ExecuteScalarAsync` function.
This returns an object, and apparently is not an int!

Using `Convert.ToInt32` will do the trick.